# When using Boost::mapped_file, why does the size of the file appear to cap at 65,356 bytes?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-alignment, memory-mapped-files

For my program, I am using boost::mapped_file to memory map a file that I want to access for a pattern detection algorithm. In order to test the construction of the mapped files, and the following execution of my algorithm I have been testing the mapping of the file by specifying the size of the file that I want, creating the file and filling it with random characters, and then mapping that file. The problem is that I have run into a weird error, and I am not quite sure what is happening.

**The error I am getting is that once my file reaches size=65,536 bytes, when attempting to use the boost::mapped_file_source::size() method, the return value is 0. Any file sizes that I try to use after this are just an incremented version of 65,536 meaning that a file size=65,538 returns a size of 2.**

I was curious if this had to do with the alignment of the mapped file, which I saw referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614516/boost-mapped-file-source-alignment-and-page-size). However, when I called the boost::mapped_file_source::alignment() method, it returned 4096, which I don't understand. What does alignment mean, and how does it play into this problem?

Also, why does boost::mapped_file_source::size() return 0 when the `file_size>65,536 bytes`? I know that 65,536 is equal to the alignment value (4096) * 16, but I don't understand why.

Comment: 65536 is 2^16 so you either run on a platform where `std::fpos` is 16-bit wide, or there is some truncation to `unsigned short` elsewhere in the code not shown.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @dxiv you were exactly right, I was truncating the size to an unsigned short. `short unsigned int size=mappedfile->mapfile.size();`

Answer (score 1):

You should show the relevant code. [Docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file_source)

```
 explicit mapped_file_source( const std::string& path,
                             size_type length = max_length,
                             boost::intmax_t offset = 0 );
```

Specifically, if `length` is not specified it will use the filesize.

Boost IOStreams does NOT have the limitation you describe, as you can easily show:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63f3d624620af2b2)**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static constexpr auto PATH = "path";

void test(std::size_t length) {
    int fd =::creat(PATH, 0600);
    if (::ftruncate(fd, length) || ::close(fd))
        ::perror("whoops");

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source m(PATH);
    std::cout
        << m.size() << " = "
        << std::hex << std::showbase << m.size() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    test(0XFFFF);
    test(0X1FFFF);
    test(0X2FFFF);
}
```

Prints

```
65535 = 0xffff
0x1ffff = 0x1ffff
0x2ffff = 0x2ffff
```

Comment: Yup, thank you I had unknowingly truncated the size of the file to an unsigned short, which is where the cutoff came from.